# How to Deploy Excel addIn project with user defined function developed in c# with setup wizard?

Tags: c#, installation, excel-formula, vsto, excel-addins

I have developed an Excel add-in application with a [User Defined Function (UDF)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/creating-custom-functions-HA001111701.aspx) in c#. I have created an installer `.vsto` file using the [setup wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx). It's working fine and my ribbon gets loaded in Excel.

The problem is that when I try to insert a UDF function in my worksheet, the function is not visible in my function wizard or does not load.

Why is this happening and what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

VSTO IS NOT DESIGNED TO SUPPORT UDFs, if you really need to have UDFs for Excel written in C# (or .NET generally), you have some solutions to choose from, includes, but not limited to:

- Automation (COM) Add-ins: [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2004/12/01/273127.aspx) is a good article about this.
- Excel DNA: a free and open source project, available at:
  http://excel-dna.net/
- Addin Express: Which is a commercial product:
  http://www.add-in-express.com/docs/net-excel-udf-tips.php

Finally, a good [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/606446/UsingplusC-plus-NETplusUserplusDefinedplusFuncti) to read about UDFs.

Comment: Is there any way to create setup installer for excel add-in with UDF functions?? Because I have to give it to the user for installing on there machine. I have search in excel-dna but didn't get any success.

Comment: There is a WiX installer project for Excel-DNA here: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/WiXInstaller